# Problem logging in to outlook.com with my MS account

Tags: outlook.com

Am very excited by the new web mail client at outlook.com. When I try to login, I am still ending up in the old hotmail client. I've searched the forums for clues as to how to get around this – but most people say that when they get into the Hotmail client, they are prompted to convert to outlook.com – I don't seem to get that option.

My Microsoft account id is actually a gmail address, not a hotmail address. I wonder if that's why this happens. I also happen to have a hotmail account – when I login with that one, I go straight to the new outlook.com client.

I've tried renaming my microsoft account to a hotmail address, but it won't let me

Answer (score 1):

When you log in into your Hotmail client, you should be able to go to `Options` and then choose `Upgrade to Outlook.com`

[image]
It also should not matter, what you use as login to your Windows Live account - it can be even GMail.

Answer (score 0):

The two clients should be completely separate. Hell, even if you were logging into two different gmail accounts by default they are separate (gmail will force logout of one or both after a short time, in fact).

Gmail and hotmail have nothing to do with one another; so I'd say that your account id has little to do with this problem. However, of course, both outlook and hotmail are Microsoft programmes.

Are you actually logging into your outlook account at all - that is, are you seeing your outlook emails? I am assuming that you are not - but do you have a separate id and password bor hotmail and outlook or is it shared between them?

I'd see possible options being the closing of your hotmail account, or a third party programme which can import (IMAP/POP3) incoming e-mails to both accounts.

Comment: It is possible to use GMail with Hotmail! You can use any email as Microsoft Account, and outlook.com will use that to send "on behalf of". Incoming is more tricky, as you need to set fetching mail with POP3/IMAP.